# I have two wires from ceiling red and black please how do I connect it to a switch fan remote then the remote to a fan so as to control the fan speed

Tags: wiring

How can I connect a fan to a fan switch controller which is connected to the ceiling that has only red and black wire

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement! If you take the [tour] you can get examples of specific questions that attract quality answers. Can you add a photo of the fixture box, and a photo of the switch? As it stands this question is very vague and difficult to answer.

Comment: There should be some information or a diagram on the fan switch controller. We'll need that.

Comment: Can you please post photos of the insides of the fan and switch boxes please?

Comment: Also, where do you live?  Probably North America but wire coloring varies by region